# Mesclando duas colunas em uma nova coluna de nome 'Classe' (dataframe Pandas)

Tags: pandas

```
df_downsampled[df_downsampled['attack_cat']=="DoS"]
```

Pega todo o dataframe 'df_downsampled' onde a coluna 'attack_cat' tem o valor DoS.

Dataset: https://www.unsw.adfa.edu.au/unsw-canberra-cyber/cybersecurity/ADFA-NB15-Datasets/

```
colunas = ['srcip','sport','dstip','dsport','proto','state','dur','sbytes', 'dbytes','sttl','dttl',
             'sloss','dloss','service','Sload','Dload','Spkts','Dpkts','swin','dwin','stcpb','dtcpb',

             'smeansz','dmeansz','trans_depth','res_bdy_len','Sjit','Djit','Stime','Ltime','Sintpkt',

             'Dintpkt','tcprtt','synack','ackdat','is_sm_ips_ports','ct_state_ttl','ct_flw_http_mthd',
             'is_ftp_login','ct_ftp_cmd','ct_srv_src','ct_srv_dst','ct_dst_ltm','ct_src_ltm','ct_src_dport_ltm',
             'ct_dst_sport_ltm','ct_dst_src_ltm','attack_cat','Label' ]

UNSW1 = pd.read_csv('/home/users/p02543/ddos/UNSW-NB15_1.csv',dtype={"srcip":object ,},names = colunas)

UNSW2= pd.read_csv('/home/users/p02543/ddos/UNSW-NB15_2.csv',dtype={"srcip":object ,},names = colunas)

UNSW3= pd.read_csv('/home/users/p02543/ddos/UNSW-NB15_3.csv',dtype={"srcip":object ,},names = colunas)

UNSW4= pd.read_csv('/home/users/p02543/ddos/UNSW-NB15_4.csv',dtype={"srcip":object ,},names = colunas)


UNSW = pd.concat([UNSW1,UNSW2,UNSW3,UNSW4])

  previsores = UNSW.iloc[:,UNSW.columns.isin(('Sload','Dload',
                                                       'Spkts','Dpkts','swin','dwin','smeansz','dmeansz',
    'Sjit','Djit','Sintpkt','Dintpkt','tcprtt','synack','ackdat','ct_srv_src','ct_srv_dst','ct_dst_ltm',
     'ct_src_ltm','ct_src_dport_ltm','ct_dst_sport_ltm','ct_dst_src_ltm')) ].values# atributos previsores
```

Existem duas colunas que quero "mesclar":

uma chama-se "Label" e tem valor 1 quando é ataque, e 0 em caso contrário.

Na coluna 'attack_cat' me interessa apenas quando seu valor é 'DoS' (e nesta caso, o valor da coluna 'Label' é 1)

Objetivo:

Criar uma nova coluna de nome "Classe" que:

Pegue APENAS os valores da coluna 'Label' quando o valor de attack_cat for 'DoS' (e o valor de' Label' for 1)

(existem outros valores em 'attack_cat' que nao me interessam)

Pegue TODOS os valores da coluna 'Label ' quando for 0 (nao ataque)

Como fazer?

Comment: Olá, está um pouco confuso. Um exemplo de um dataframe que tens e do que pretendes como resultado ajudava.

Comment: @Miguel: Editei a pergunta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da maneira com que a pergunta está formulada entendi que você precisa de uma só coluna que tenha os valores de Label quando attack_cat = "DoS" e os valores de Label quando Label = 0, e para isso a solução seria algo como:

```
df_downsampled['Classe'] = pd.concat([(df_downsampled.Label[df_downsampled.attack_cat[df_downsampled.Label == 1]]) , (df_downsampled.Label[df_downsampled.Label == 0])], ignore_index=True)
```

E para evitar os dados que são NaN, chame a coluna como:

```
df_downsample.Classe.dropna()
```

Para um novo dataset com o filtro de attack_cat = "DoS" você precisa de:

```
new_df_downsampled = pd.concat([df_downsampled[df_downsampled['attack_cat']=="DoS"],df_downsampled[df_downsampled.Label==0]])
```

Comment: os valores de Label quando Label = 1 E attack_cat ='DoS' e os valores de Label quando Label = 0

Comment: Tudo em uma mesma coluna? Com alguma ordenação específica? @EdS

Comment: tudo na mesma coluna. Gostaria de manter na ordem que vem do dataset, pois a nova coluna será usada em algoritmo de Machine Learning!

Comment: Tente o que editei agora.

Comment: Vou testar! Neste código será mantida a ordem do dataset?

Comment: EU recebi o seguinte erro: " ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: Pode tentar agora? @EdS A ordem será: attack_cat, depois os labels na ordem que estão no dataset.

Comment: nao deu erro mas o resultado está errado: estao aparecendo valores onde Label = 1 mas  attack_cat != 'DoS (estes nao me interessam)

Comment: Eu queria filtrar assim: df_downsampled[df_downsampled['attack_cat']=="DoS"] ou df_downsampled[df_downsampled['Label']==0]]  mas nao sei como fazer o OR acima!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84212/discussion-between-vitoriahmc-and-ed-s).